Socket.io events in React.js and Node.js are not being triggered
I'm building a chat application in React js and Node js.
The events that I have written in React.js and Node.js do not seem to be triggered. I can login and see data in both the browser and the console, but as soon as I installed Socket.IO for the client and server, not only did I get issues from Socket.IO on the client side, none of the events are being triggered.
socketConnect.js in the client side
import { useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client"

function useSocket (user, dispatch) {

    useEffect(() => {

        const socket = socketIOClient.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000")

        socket.emit("join", user)

        socket.on("typing", (user) => {
            console.log("Event", user)
        })

        socket.on("friends", (friends) => {
            console.log("Friends", friends)
        })

        socket.on("online", (user) => {
            console.log("Online", user)
        })

        socket.on("offline", (user) => {
            console.log("Offline", user)
        })
    }, [dispatch])

}

export default useSocket

/socket/index.js in the server side
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const { sequelize } = require("../models");

const users = new Map();
const userSockets = new Map();
const SocketServer = (server) => {

    const io = socketIo(server)
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        socket.on("join", async (user) => {
            let sockets = [];
            if (user.has(user.id)){
                const existingUser = users.get(user.id)
                existingUser.sockets = [...existingUser.sockets, ... [socket.id]]
                users.set(user.id, existingUser);
                sockets = [...existingUser.sockets, ... [socket.id]]
                userSockets.set(socket.id, user.id)
            } else {
                users.set(user.id, {id: user.id, sockets: [socket.id]})
                sockets.push(socket.id);
                userSockets.set(socket.id, user.id)
            }
            const onlineFriends = []; 

            const chatters = getChatters(user.id) 

            console.log(chatters);

            for (let i = 0; i < chatters.length; i++){
                if (users.has(chatters[i])){
                    const chatter = users.get(chatters[i])
                    chatter.sockets.forEach(socket => {
                        
                        try {
                            io.to(socket).emit("online",user);
                        } catch (error) {
                            
                        }

                    })
                    onlineFriends.push(chatter.id)
                }
            }
            sockets.forEach(socket => {
                try {
                    io.to(socket).emit("friends", onlineFriends)

                } catch (error) {
                    
                }
            })

            console.log("New User Joined: ", user.firstName);

            io.to(socket.id).emit("typing", "User typing...")

        })

        socket.on("disconnect", async () => {

            if (userSockets.has(socket.id)){

                const user = users.get(userSockets.get(socket.id))

                if (user.sockets.length > 1) {

                    user.sockets = user.sockets.filter(sock => {

                        if (sock !== socket.id) return true

                        userSockets.delete(sock)
                        return false
                    })

                    users.set(user.id, user)
                } else {
                    
                    const chatters = await getChatters(user.id)

                    for (let i = 0; i < chatters.length; i++){
                        if (users.has(chatters[i])){
                            users.get(chatters[i]).sockets.forEach(socket => {
                                
                                try {
                                    io.to(socket).emit("offline",user);
                                } catch (error) {
                                    
                                }
        
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    userSockets.delete(socket.id);  
                    users.delete(user.id)
                }
            }
        });
    })
}

const getChatters = async (userId) => {

    try {

        const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(`
        select "cu"."userId" from "ChatUsers" as cu
        inner join (
            select "c"."id" from "Chats" as c
            where exists (
                select "u"."id" from "Users" as u
                inner join "ChatUsers" on u.id = "ChatUsers"."userId"
                where u.id = ${parseInt(userId)} and c.id = "ChatUsers"."chatId"
            )
        ) as cjoin on cjoin.id = "cu"."chatId"
        where "cu"."userId" != ${parseInt(userId)}
    `)

        return results.length > 0 ? results.map(el => el.userId) : []

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return []
    }
}

module.exports = SocketServer


root index.js in the server side
const express = require("express");
const config = require('./config/app')
const router = require('./router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));

const port = config.appPort;

const server = http.createServer(app);
const SocketServer = require("./socket")
const io = socketIo(server);

SocketServer(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("New client connected: ", socket.id);

    socket.on("join", (user) => {
        console.log("New user joined: ", user);
        io.to(socket.id).emit("typing", "User typing...");
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected: ", socket.id);
    });
});



server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)    
});




Chat.js which renders the components
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import useSocket from './hooks/socketConnect'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import { fetchChats } from '../../store/actions/chat'
import FriendList from './components/FriendList/FriendList'
import Messenger from './components/Messenger/Messenger'
import './Chat.scss'

const Chat = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const user = useSelector(state => state.authReducer.user)

    useSocket(user, dispatch)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchChats()).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <div id='chat-container'>
            <Navbar />
            <div id='chat-wrap'>
                <FriendList />
                <Messenger />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat

I have multiple users in the database. When a user logs in and is online, another user from the database, if logged in, will be notified from the console, but none of the events are being triggered.
